Implementing CSS variables for large web systems
I am a frontend developer and I am working on a big project that demands me to implement support for mobile and dakr mode. Since this project has dozens of modules, I am thinking about how the dark mode will be implemented and how much work I'll have.
So, I have these global css variables and, as you can see, I have one 'light' variations and one 'dark'. For now, I am switching between light-dark depending on context, sometimes having
light-dark(var(--c_dark_5), var(--c_light_4)) and sometimes light-dark(var(--c_dark_5), var(--c_light_5)). My question is: can I always keep the same pattern like always using the light nº 5 to the dark nº 5 or I should still manage each context separatly?
--c_light_5: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
--c_light_4: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
--c_light_3: hsl(0, 0%, 93%);
--c_light_2: hsl(0, 0%, 88%);
--c_light_1: hsl(0, 0%, 74%);
--c_dark_1: hsl(0, 0%, 46%);
--c_dark_2: hsl(0, 0%, 38%);
--c_dark_3: hsl(0, 0%, 26%);
--c_dark_4: hsl(0, 0%, 25.88%);
--c_dark_5: hsl(0, 0%, 12%);

